# Automate the Boring Stuff - Shutil.copy() function - No such file/folder error

Tags: python

I am also having difficulty getting this code to run correctly. Per the book (automate the boring stuff with python 2), this code is supposed to create a copy of the spam.txt file in a new folder, namely 'some_folder". (If I understand correctly.)

Instead it only creates a file called some_folder in the home folder (when opened with notepad, that file is then the copy of the spam.txt file.

```
import shutil, os
from pathlib import Path
p = Path.home()
shutil.copy(p / 'spam.txt', p / 'some_folder')
```

I have seen a similar question asked but the issue they had was the spam.txt file had not been created. I have the spam.txt file, my issue is the output is not a copied file under a new 'some_folder' folder.

Comment: `shutil.copy` doesn't actually create a folder when you use it, it only copies INTO the path you give it. Is the folder `some_folder` already created?

Comment: Thank you. I only realized this after rereading the passage for the 10th time.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I misunderstood. The new folder is supposed to already be created. This will not lead to a new folder being created.

Comment: You will also need to write `shutil.copy(p + '/spam.txt', p + '/some_folder')` or it won't work

Comment: I believe you may be correct. I will keep this in mind.